# I need an admin toolset for Windows 2003 and 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring

i know this is way too general question but anyway.

I need few tools, will write down my tasks as sysadmin and if you have any to automate my job i would be glad to hear. I don't mind paying for software needed unless it is way too expensive.

First of i backup all files on server at local/office storage. I 7zip all SQL backup files and then move them over network to centralized location and then FTP them from office PC which has no FTP server installed and cannot have one. Backups happen at 4AM at the morning thus i need to set time for compressing and afterward FTPing. Then i FTP all IIS web application as differentiation backup, same goes for VOD movies.

Second tool i need is system monitor which will monitor all servers from themselves and from external location for CPU/Memory/Hard disk and other basic failures. This tool should able to execute Website address with parameters which will send me an email with all report on failure.

Third tool i need is a way to get all Event Logs from 10 Windows based servers without accessing each any of them manually.

If you know any solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a Windows Scheduled Task to run a batch file to do all my zipping at 3am.  Then at 5am [WS_FTP](http://www.ipswitchft.com/) is scheduled to FTP the files to my archive machine.

2 and 3 could both be handled by a variety of server monitoring products.  We use [PA Server Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/servermonitor) with the exception that I'm not sure it can send email via URL, but it can definitely send email directly.

Comment: Cheers for PA Server Monitor, this is tool i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

1. [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) should help centralize backups to another server.
2. Do you want a monitoring system like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)? or an inventory system like [OCSInventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/)?  It sounds more like monitoring (NMS), so there are many good options. You may need to setup SNMP for each device you're monitoring.
3. Consider setting up [syslog for windows.](http://troy.jdmz.net/syslogwin/)

Comment: Anything is Windows based or related to Windows 2008?